# issue in understanding concept of loading data in pagination with javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have lots of data and I want to make a pagination so I am able to load 5 items per page and I want to have 10 pages. I am trying to get inspired by http://addyosmani.com/blog/backbone-paginator-new-pagination-components-for-backbone-js/

```
<ul class="pagination" id="paginationSelect">



            <% for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){ %>
                <% if(i === 0){ %>
                    <li><a id="a-page-item"  class="page">Previous</a></li>

                <% } else if(i > 0 && i < 10 - 1){ %>
                    <li><a id="a-page-item"  class="page"> <%= i %> </a></li>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>

        <li class="arrow"><a href="">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2151/ this jsfiddle is without css of course) My problem is that when I click on each of the pages (from 1 to 10 ) it loads data from 1 to 5 ( and all of them are the same ) but how can I have 5 data on first page, next 5 data on the second page and so on.

```
event : {

"click #paginationSelect" : "fetchSelectedData"
}

onPageClick : function() {

            console.log("you clickedddd");

            this.collection.setPagination(1, 5);
            this.collection.setNrPages(5);

            this.collection.reset();
            this.$("#listMessages").empty(); //listMessage is a placeholder for showing data
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
```

Comment: Pass different values to `this.collection.setPagination()` with each click.

Comment: how can I continue from the last loaded page? suppose I want to start from 6 on page 2 (since there are already 5 pages loaded on page 1) How can I do that each time and keep the index ?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.Paginator provides implementation of two main pagination approaches - server side paging (**Backbone.Paginator.requestPager**) and client side paging (**Backbone.Paginator.clientPager**).

It's not clear which one do you use, so could you please provide source code for your collection ?

As for HTML template I'd propose you to change it to something like this:

```
<ul class="pagination" id="paginationSelect">

        <li><a id="previous-page" class="page">Previous</a></li>

        <% for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) { %>
                <li><a id="page" class="page"><%= i %></a></li>
        <% } %>

        <li><a id="next-page" class="page">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
```

and update event handlers to be (in case you use **requestPager**):

```
event : {"click #previous-page" : "previousPage",
         "click #next-page" : "nextPage",
         "click #page" : "page"},

previousPage : function(e) {
  this.collection.requestPreviousPage();
},

nextPage : function(e) {
  this.collection.requestNextPage();
},

page : function() {
  var page = $(e.target).text();
  this.collection.goTo(page);
},
```

Backbone.Paginator will automatically fetch required data once you call methods like requestPreviousPage(), requestNextPage(), goTo(pageNumber) from collection.

BTW, there are quite good examples of using both **Backbone.Paginator.requestPager** and **Backbone.Paginator.clientPager** on plugin's github examples folder: [Backbone.Paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator), so you might take a look at them.

Just one note: to make examples work you'd need to change URL in **PaginatedCollection.js** to `https://api.github.com/repos/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator/issues?` because URL used in examples doesn't return any data. In client-paging example you'd also need to comment out **server_api** section in the same file, so it would work more like client-side paging.